# M6 toll payment

Tags: uk, driving, tolls

I am an EU student, based in the UK. I just started travelling through the UK by car, and I am very confused about the M6 toll. I was coming from Manchester, going to London, and got close to M6 toll, with a lot of indicators regarding prices and related stuff. At a jonction (can't pinpoint where), on the right there was the toll plaza. As indicated by the navigation system, I took to the right. What I am afraid I have done is to take a detour for cars with tags, thus avoiding the payment.

Coming with a more concrete question, did I mistakenly avoid the payment? What can I do in this regard (there does not seem to be a way to pay online)?

Comment: For your last question: just Google M6 toll. You'll find the site where you can pay. That's how I did it when I entered the toll part unexpectedly (in a Dutch car).

Comment: If you're carrying an Android phone with location history enabled you'll be able to confirm you used the toll road but unlikely to be accurate enough to tell you which lane.

Comment: First thing I do in a place is get a toll-tag. And a transit pass. The new trend is to have no toll booths at all, and simply deal kindly to people with no tags who willingly pay up (Golden Gate Bridge).  That's not true everywhere, EZpass (the US northeast) are total jerks.

Comment: You say you were using satnav. But satnav advises something like "this is a toll route, do you want to avoid it?"

Comment: @WeatherVane that's an extremely general statement, and I know (since my satnav app doesn't say that) that not all satnavs do.  I agree that *if* the OP's satnav had given such advice, *then* it's a shame (s)he didn't heed it; but assuming it did and (at least implicitly) chiding the OP for ignoring it seems a wee bit harsh.

Comment: You might not remember exactly, but is there any chance you could look on Google Street View down to try and see which lane you traveled down?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions.  Putting on hold for now.

Comment: The M6 tool booths *all* have barriers, even the tag lane has a barrier. The barrier raises when your tag is scanned automatically, Its not possible to go through without paying.

Comment: Finally, after a few months and a few trips on the motorway, found the answer. There are 2 different highways, named rather confusingly M6 and M6 toll. I have thought M6 toll is related to the place where you pay the toll for M6 or about the payment itself.